# Trim a string, with arbitrary number of underscores, until a set number of underscores remain

Tags: string, applescript

We start with 2 strings. I want to trim both strings to contain exactly 4 underscores. The thing is they can contain any number of underscores, to a minimum of 4.

For example:

```
With_1_Underscores_To_Much_Here

With_2_More_Underscores_To_Much_Here
```

So the end output would be:

```
With_1_Underscores_To_Much

With_2_More_Underscores_To
```

I've tried using the subroutine explained [here](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html), but it's the random number of underscores that is causing me issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your original strings contain at least 4 underscores, then this should work. If you have fewer than 4 it will generate an error.

Essentially, it cycles through each string in a list and uses the underscore to delimit each text, breaking it into 'text items'. It then grabs the first five of them and rejoins them.

```
set ab to {"With_1_Underscores_To_Much_Here", "With_2_More_Underscores_To_Much_Here"}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "_"
set shStr to {}
repeat with x in ab
    set xy to text items 1 thru 5 of x
    set xyz to xy as text
    set end of shStr to xyz
end repeat
shStr
```

Comment: RE: "If you have fewer than 4 it will generate an error." --  Then why not include some _error handling_, it really wouldn't be that hard to do!

Comment: Besides it being an endless journey? The question specifies that there are a minimum of 4 in each string. Also, it does not specify what it should be done in such a scenario, resulting in a more complicated answer predicated on speculation. Discretion is the better part of valour.

Comment: I should add that it's quite possible that the original script may already have a method of insuring that all strings have the requisite composition by this stage. I have a modified version with some error handling. If the OP sees some value in it, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following example shown in the question:

```
With_1_Underscores_To_Much_Here

With_2_More_Underscores_To_Much_Here
```

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, will return:

```
With_1_Underscores_To_Much

With_2_More_Underscores_To
```

**Just as it is shown in question!**

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property delim : "_"

set myStrings to ¬
    "With_1_Underscores_To_Much_Here
    
With_2_More_Underscores_To_Much_Here"


set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
    {AppleScript's text item delimiters, delim}

set newStringsList to {}
repeat with thisString in paragraphs of myStrings
    set delimCount to (length of text items of thisString) - 1
    if delimCount ≥ 4 then
        set thisString to text items 1 thru 5 of thisString
        set thisString to thisString as string
        copy thisString to end of newStringsList
    end if
end repeat

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed & linefeed
set myNewStrings to newStringsList as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

return myNewStrings
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* includes just a bit of *error handling*, so if a *string* has less than four *delimiters* it will not error out. It also provides a manner to do something else with a *string* not meeting the requirements by expanding the `if` *statement* with an `else` or `else if` *clause*.

As the intent of **AppleScript** is to be English like and very human readable, the *names* of the *variables* impart what they are, and not cryptic as the examples in the other answer.

Proper *coding* typically dictates that when using **AppleScript**'s *text item delimiters*, one always resets it to what it originally was, because in not doing so there is the potential to have issues. Thus the *example* **AppleScript** *code* includes a manner of proper use of setting **AppleScript**'s *text item delimiters*. Note however, there can be exceptions to the rules.

When using **AppleScript**'s *text item delimiters* it is normal to coerce different *types* of *variables* from one *type* to another, and there is not necessarily an express need to create additional *variables* to do this. For example, instead of doing this:

```
set xyz to xy as text
```

I simple do:

```
set thisString to thisString as string
```

Which coerces the first `thisString`, which is a *list* of *text items*, to `thisString` as a *string*, without the need to interject additional *variables*.

I'm mentioning these things so as one goes forward learning how to *code* one writes *code* that reads easy and will be easily understandable when one looks at it days, weeks, months later. It's also a good practice to comment one *code*, although I didn't do it here as its a very short amount of it.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>